# Why are my values not copying to another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have read other posts and I still can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong... I have two workbooks, one with the code in it (Sheet1 is the codename of the sheet I want to copy values from) and another workbook defined as "y" in this example. I want to copy over the value of K1 in Sheet1 into cell F5 of workbook y.

Nothing is happening when I hit the Command button (It is an activex commandbutton, so I have put it in the Worksheet, thank you Rory for verifying), nothing is pasting over to workbook "y". I have double checked the file paths and the sheet names as well, they are correct

```
Private Sub Commandbutton1_Click()
Dim y As Workbook
Set y = Workbooks.Open("FILEPATH\Databases\Test 2.xlsm")
Sheet1.Unprotect "Swarf"
y.Unprotect "Swarf"
y.Sheets("Mytest2").Range("F5").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Mytest1").Range("K1").Value

y.Protect "Swarf"
y.Close SaveChanges = True
Sheet1.Protect “Swarf”

End Sub
```

[image: Here is a screenshot of the VBA code]

[image: This is the Workbook where the code is being written]

[image: This is workbook "y", where I want to paste the values]

Comment: If you're using an activex commandbutton, that declaration is wrong - it should be: `Private Sub Commandbutton1_Click()`. If it's a Form control, the routine should be public, in a normal module, and then assigned to the button as a macro.

Comment: Yes you are correct, I was missing the " _Click", and I put this in the codename Sheet1 of my code, should I do "Public Sub Commandbutton1_Click()" as opposed to "Private Sub Commandbutton1_Click()"

Comment: If it's activex then it should be in the worksheet code module.

Comment: It is an activex commandbutton, and I have it in the worksheet module, why is it not working?

Comment: if you put your cursor in that routine, do you see `CommandButton1` in the left hand dropdown at the top of the code window and `Click` in the right hand dropdown? If not, either the commandbutton name is different, or that's not the sheet the button is on. (or it's not activex)

Comment: I just deleted the button, inserted it again as an activex commandbutton, and put it into design mode and right-clicked and selected "View code" and it took me to "Sheet1(Mytest1)", which is under Microsoft Excel Objects, so this is a worksheet (the only worksheet, because I'm just using this as a test for a much bigger code)

Comment: That should have created a `Click` event procedure for you, so just put your code in there.

Comment: I have added screenshots, I don't understand what you mean Rory

Comment: Make sure you include all workbook references too.

Comment: what do you mean by that SJR, I'm still new to excel and VB

Comment: `Sheet1.Range("K1").Value` should have a workbook reference otherwise will refer to active workbook. Btw use @SJR etc and we are notified of your replies.

Comment: Oh okay @rory what do you mean, I have posted screenshots now

Comment: @SJR okay got it, how do I create a workbook reference (I'm very new to excel excuse me)

Comment: Well you have one here `y.Sheets("Mytest2").Range("F5").Value` so same principle. You need to specify your source workbook (`thisworkbook` if it's the one containing your code) - plenty of info online on this.

Comment: @SJR I have looked and I changed it to y.Sheets("Mytest2").Range("F5").Value=ThisWorkbook.Sheets.("Mytest1").Range("K1").Value and it still doesn't work (I have edited the post's code as well to reflect this suggestion)

Comment: Add a `Msgbox "running"` line to the code just to check it's actually running at all.

Comment: can you please check my new thread, I have figured out something different using loops but I need some help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59110114/running-a-for-loop-with-a-nested-do-while-statement-but-why-is-my-code-freezing