# Running a For loop with a nested Do While statement, but why is my code freezing?

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, do-while

I have two workbooks, one with the Code INSIDE of it Sheet1 (which is the codename of the sheet I want to copy values from) and another workbook defined as "y" in this example. I want to copy over the values of cell "K1-K10" in Sheet1 into cell ("F1-F10") of workbook y (For example, I want F1.Value=K1.Value, F2.Value = K2.Value, etc...).

Both workbooks are protected with a password, I am only trying to copy values from Sheet1 (that is why I don't unprotect it), but I want to save, close and protect workbook "y" once all of the values copy and paste into it.

When I hit the Activex Commandbutton inside Sheet1, the code is freezing up my workbook. I have double checked the file paths and the sheet names as well, they are correct.

I have also posted screenshots of the code and both workbooks below:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim y As Workbook
Dim i As Integer

Set y = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="\\FILEPATH\Test 2.xlsm", Password:="Swarf")


    With y

        For i = 1 To 10

            Do While Cells(i, 11).Value <> ""

                .Sheets("MyTest2").Unprotect "Swarf"
                .Sheets("Mytest2").Cells(i, 6).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 11).Value

            Loop

        Next i

        .Password = "Swarf"
        .Save
        .Close False

    End With

    End Sub
```

[image: VBA Code inside codename Sheet1 (Test 1.xslm workbook)]

[image: Workbook where the code is (Test 1.xslm) and values are being copied from codename Sheet1]

[image: Workbook "y" (Test 2.xlsm) where values are being pasted into]

Comment: Maybe you just need to add a point before Cells i.e. `Do While .Cells(i, 11).Value <> ""`

Comment: Properly indenting you code makes it easier to see what happens when. For instance, it makes it obvious that nothing causes the value of `cell(i, 11)` to change inside the loop. The result in an infinite loop

Comment: @Storax I tried that, and I got "Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: That's because your `with` is for a workbook, not a worksheet. Specify the worksheet those cells are on. (note that this won't remove the infinite loop

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad it has been edited (by someone else) and indented now, should be much easier to follow! and I'm trying to remove the infinite loop but unsure on how to

Comment: Why are you not just copying the range?

Comment: @GMalc I want to make sure that the cell is not empty and has some value inside of it!

Comment: Oh, yes. Then just add the sheet, too. `Do While .Sheets("MyTest2").Cells(i, 11).Value <> ""`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do need use `While Loop` for this case.

Use `If` will be solved your issue.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim y As Workbook
Dim i As Integer

Set y = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="\\FILEPATH\Test 2.xlsm", Password:="Swarf")


    With y

        For i = 1 To 10

            If (Cells(i, 11).Value <> "") Then

                .Sheets("MyTest2").Unprotect "Swarf"
                .Sheets("Mytest2").Cells(i, 6).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 11).Value

            End If

        Next i

        .Password = "Swarf"
        .Save
        .Close False

    End With

    End Sub
```

Because you will cause infinity loop for your `while loop` statement.
For example: `i=1`,then the statement `Cells(i, 11).Value <> ""` always return true and continue looping.

Comment: Okay so I understand the loop is causing an infinite loop and continuing to just loop through, but where do I put the if statement? can you please show me

Comment: I already updated my answer with code which require to amend.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to loop, you can just transfer the information of the complete range in one go something like:

```
    With y
        .Sheets("MyTest2").Unprotect "Swarf"
        .Sheets("Mytest2").Range("F1:F10").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("K1:K10").Value
    End With
```

There are plenty of posts on SO about finding the last row of a column if you really have a problem copying empty cells